# Failed to read environment Variables in Scala using $ symbol

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j, cloudera

Adding Property in Scala Environment Properties

```
val sysProps = System.getProperties
sysProps.setProperty("current.date.time", LocalDateTime.now().toString())
```

i'm able to save this property.

I tried accessing this property(`current.date.time`) in log4j.properties like below

```
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Users/vsami/Desktop/Demo_${current.date.time}.log
log4j.appender.file.File=C:/Users/vsami/Desktop/Demo_${env:current.date.time}.log
```

Log file is getting generated in above location like `Demo_.log`, Expected :- `Demo_2019/11/27T13:21:00.log`

Above implementation is not helping me in accessing variable from environment properties and generate log file with expected naming convention.

Comment: please share the error you receive, if at all

Comment: Maybe the system property was set too late (after Log4J already initialized itself).

Comment: JVM system properties are not the same as environment variables. I don't think you can set environment variables from within the JVM. And as @Thilo pointed out, even if you could then Log4J might have already initialized itself before your code manages to set the environment variable.

Comment: @Thilo, yes you are correct - I tried setting system property before initializing log4j, it worked and file is getting generated in expected manner - Thanks for the Suggestion.

Comment: @Thilo, in local i'm able to generate the logs in expected manner by initializing log4j after - when i tried to do the same in cloudera environment i'm not getting the expected result - am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

JVM has properties that can be passed via `-D` parameter at VM boot. `-Dprop=value`. 
These properties can be read via `System.getProperties` API call. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for more info.

Environment variables are not specified on JVM boot and managed independently from VM by your boot environment (it can be shell, bash etc). You cannot change environment variables in already running VM. These variables can be read via `System.getenv()`

`$` is a look up operator in [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html) and can be used to resolve env variables with `env:` prefix or [Main Arguments Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#AppMainArgsLookup)  with prefix `main:`.

You could use `main:current.date.time` and initialise your value as following

```
MainMapLookup.setMainArguments(Array("--current.date.time", LocalDateTime.now().toString()));
```

Make sure that `MainMapLookup` is called before logging is initialised.